# WWW vs non WWW -- What's the best practice? I need to pick one for my new SSL Certificate

Tags: security, http, ssl, dns, openssl

Should my site be a www or non-www address? This is a pretty basic question. I wanted to see what people consider to be the best practice here. The reason I have to pick is I need to buy an SSL certificate for one or the other. Of course I can redirect to the one I pick on the back-end and the technicals are not a problem, but are there any opinions on which to pick and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My vote is for the shorter one. Comparing your question to writing for the web, and writing in general - strive for maximum salience in the fewest words possible. 4 saved bytes can come in handy with 3rd party services like Twitter.

Comment: I like this answer most because it answers my broader dilemma rather than focusing on the technical issues. The reasoning is sound and practical. Thank you.

Comment: @TomD: I think you need to do both. If you do the shorter one as suggested here then users who type `https :// www.site.com` will get the dreaded browser warning.

Comment: Hi GregS. Thank you for your comment. I disagree to an extent. This particular site just has a small secure area -- the rest is public and static. I think if I was running a bank site or a site that needs global SSL I would worry about that but honestly I don't want people who type in https: // www.example.com to put extra load on my server for no reason.

Comment: I think a wildcard SSL certificate will address Greg's concern.

Answer (score 7):

Id answer both? Some sellers will offer both as standard. I believe Go Daddy offer the service help topic below.

http://help.godaddy.com/topic/234/article/850

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I think that's how all SSL certs should be. Unfortunately the brand I wanted to buy did not make this offer. This is definitely great advice for someone who has not yet chosen a specific vendor.

Answer (score 4):

The host name is essentially a convenience for your users to remember the name. From this point of view, it's mainly a marketing decision. If you've promoted `example.com` use that, if you've promoted `www.example.com` use that.

Redirections on the back-end as you seem to suggest don't sound like a good idea. The point of the certificate is to let your user be able to verify the identity of your server. If you only have `example.com` and if they try `www.example.com` over HTTPS, they'll first get a warning about an invalid certificate (thus they shouldn't follow the redirection).

You may be able to get both. Some CAs issue certificates that have SANs for `example.com` and `www.example.com` (sometimes for the same price or a little bit more, I think).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that some CAs offer both for the same price. I think that's something people looking for a vendor should look for.

Answer (score 1):

SSL certs support multiple names and also support wildcard pattern matching. I would add 2 names to the cert; you don't need to choose just one.

Consider adding the two patterns `site.com` and `*.site.com` to cover you, if you need to use an additional hostname / subdomain in the future.

Please note that both are needed if you wish to access the server as `site.com`, as the name `site.com` does **not** match the pattern `*.site.com`

Comment: Right but all this costs money. If it were this simple, I wouldn't even waste time asking.

Comment: Unless you need Extended Validation services (EV) then SSL certificates are very cheap thesedays. If you are paying anything more than about $£€10-15, and price is they key factor for you, you may wish to consider switching supplier.

Comment: Where can I get a *.example.com (aka "wildcard") certificate for $£€10-15?

Comment: Sorry Tom, I was only meaning price per-name. Wildcards generally aren't cheap. But i've never really understood why, when most SSL issuers don't really do any validation thesedays.